# PHP: looping two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck in my self learning `PHP` because of the array looping.

Let's say I have two `arrays`, same number of elements:

```
$description
: array = 
  0: string = Name
  1: string = LastName
  2: string = Address
  3: string = City
  4: string = Country

 $value
: array = 
  0: string = Dan
  1: string = Smith
  2: string = 4, Burlington St
  3: string = London
  4: string = England
```

What should I do to print the following? :

Name: **Dan**
LastName: **Smith**
Address: **4, Burlington St**
City: **London**
Country: **England**

Comment: Since you're learning, this is a great time to learn that PHP's associative array handling is better suited to something like `array('name'=>'Dan', 'LastName'=>'Smith','Address'=>'...',....)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.array-combine.php) to merge these two arrays into one:

```
$c = array_combine($description, $value);
foreach ($c as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . ": " . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Option #1:

```
foreach($description as $key => $descText) {
    echo $descText, ': ', $value[$key], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Option #2

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($description));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($values));
foreach($mi as $detail) {
    list($descText, $descValue) = $detail;
    echo $descText, ': ', $descValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: #2 is nice, but a bit like shooting a fly with a cannon

Comment: errata fixed - and while it is a sledgehammer, I still like MultipleIterators on principle, especially when working with mismatched indexes (not the case here, I know)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($description); $i++) {
    echo $description[$i] . ': '.$value[$i] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$new_arr = array();
for(int i=0;i<count($description);$i++) {
    $new_arr[$description] = $value;
}
```

Now

```
foreach($new_arr as $key => $val) {
    echo $key . ':' .$val.'<br>';
}
```